# Share session data between sites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, session, cookies

i'm working on multisite and I'd like to share session data between two or more sites. I have session id, but what is the best way to retrieve session data from cookie store? Or it will be better to enable ActiveRecord session store and use find_by_session_id method to retrieve session data? Using this way - I need to configure one site as SessionStore provider and others will use second connection to database to retrieve session data. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't share cookies between various websites due to security issues.
Were you I would use memcached instead to share the data depending on the user ID in my user base.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but that isn't strictly true. You can't share cookies between *domains* (though you can between subdomains and a higher level domain). If you have multiple sites on the same domain, they can all get the same cookie from the user. Then you can use a database session store and a shared database and usermodel to share the session at the backend. An example of when you might use this is if you have nginx sending different paths of the same domain to different rails projects.